# Can you custom display reviewCount in Branch.io banner?

Tags: branch.io

Currently, I'm passing in the reviewCount as a number (reviewCount: 1500), so it displays like so: 

[CLICK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iATX4.png)

Is there a way to customize it so it will appear as (1,500) instead?

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch.io here:

It sounds like you're using our legacy smart banner library. This has been deprecated for a while, and so the functionality is quite basic. It doesn't offer a lot of options, including this one.

You should consider upgrading to the newer [Journeys module](https://branch.io/journeys/). It's still free for basic banners, and this formatting (`1,500`) is now the default.